# elasticsearch: unable to set geo_shape value using XContentBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have following mapping in elastic search. I am able to PUT documents using Sense plugin but unable to do so using XContentBuilder to set the **geo_shape** field value. I am getting following error:

error:

```
[106]: index [streets], type [street], id [{dc872755-f307-4c5e-93f6-bba9c95791c7}], message [MapperParsingException[failed to parse [shape]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[shape must be an object consisting of type and coordinates];]
```

mapping:

```
PUT /streets
    {
       "mappings": {
          "street": {
             "properties": {
                "id": {
                   "type": "string"
                },
                "shape": {
                   "type": "geo_shape",
                   "tree": "quadtree"
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

code:

```
val bulkRequest:BulkRequestBuilder = esClient.prepareBulk()
//inloop
    xb = jsonBuilder().startObject()      
    xb.field("id", guid)
    xb.field("shape", jsonString) // removing this line creates the index OK but without the geo_shape
    xb.endObject()
    bulkRequest.add(esClient.prepareIndex("streets", "street", guid).setSource(xb))
//end loop


    val bulkResponse:BulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet()

    if(bulkResponse.hasFailures){
          println(bulkResponse.buildFailureMessage())
    }
```

jsonString:

```
{
    "id": "{98b8fd8d-074c-4349-a83b-6e892bf2d0ef}",
    "shape": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [-70.81866815832467, 43.12187109162505],
            [-70.83054813653018, 43.15917412985851],
            [-70.81320737213957, 43.23522269547419],
            [-70.90108590067649, 43.28102004268419]
        ],
        "crs": {
            "type": "name",
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG:4326"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any feedback?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late for you, but this could help someone facing a similar issue even nowadays.

Following your index mapping for the document `streets`, we have these properties: `id` and `shape`.

In your error message, it's described that:

> shape must be an object consisting of type and coordinates

So for your concrete case, the `crs` array is just not accepted (don't know exactly why you can't add extra parameters).

This is an example for how to add a document into the `streets` index using CURL:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/streets/_doc?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
"id": 123,
"shape": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                32.85444259643555,
                39.928694653732364
            ],
            [
                32.847232818603516,
                39.9257985682691
            ],
            [
                32.837791442871094,
                39.91947941109337
            ],
            [
                32.837276458740234,
                39.91579296675271
            ],
            [
                32.85392761230469,
                39.913423004886894
            ],
            [
                32.86937713623047,
                39.91329133793421
            ],
            [
                32.88036346435547,
                39.91539797880347
            ],
            [
                32.85444259643555,
                39.928694653732364
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
}'
```

If you need to add a `LineString`, instead of a `Polygon`, just change the 'type' attribute from the 'shape'.

I hope this helps people having to add documents with shapes into an ElasticSearch database.